# Why is $(\vec{d}.\nabla)\vec{r}$ not equal to $0$? where $\vec{d}$ is a constant vector and $\vec{r}$ the position vector.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

Surely this should equal to $0$, however when looking online I see this as equal to $\vec{d}$. I thought that since $\vec{d}$ is a constant vector, when applying the divergence, it should be $0$?

If anyone could shed light on this it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\vec{d} = \sum d_x \hat x$

So,

$\begin{align}&\vec d \cdot \nabla = (d_{x_1}\hat{x_1} + d_{x_2}\hat{x_2} +\cdots d_{x_n}\hat{x_n})\cdot(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\hat{x_1} + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}\hat{x_2} +\cdots \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\hat{x_n}) \\&= d_{x_1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} + d_{x_2}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_2}+ \cdots d_{x_n}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\\&=\sum d_x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\end{align}$

Also, $\vec{r} = \sum x \hat x$

$\Rightarrow (\vec d \cdot \nabla)\vec r = \left[\sum d_x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right](\sum x \hat x) =\sum d_x \hat x= \vec d$

Comment: I guess this makes sense, but the part that troubles me is the 2nd line. Why isn't that equal to 0? As surely when we do $\vec d \cdot \nabla = \sum d_x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$, aren't we differentiating a constant vector? I.e. isn't $\vec d \cdot \nabla = \sum d_x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ = $\nabla \cdot \vec d = \sum \frac{\partial}{\partial x} d_x$

Comment: @jambajuice could you get that now?

Comment: See comment above sorry

Comment: @jambajuice no $\vec d \cdot \nabla$ is not same as $\nabla \cdot \vec d$

Comment: @prAnjal Yep, just now reloaded the page and saw the edit.

Comment: Why is it not the same though?

Comment: Actually I think I understand it if I think about it logically, and about the order of the operations. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. As it's a dot product we can understand the product by considering a single term.

$d_x \frac{\partial}{\partial x}[ \vec{f}(x,y,\cdots) ]\ne  (\frac{\partial}{\partial x}d_x) (\vec{f}(x,y,\cdots) ) (=0)  $